# invalid operands to binary expression ('basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >' and 'vector<std::string>' (aka 'vector<basic_string<char> >'))

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, operator-overloading, stdvector, cout

I am trying to do a program to check for all permutations of a word. Link to Codewars Kata: https://www.codewars.com/kata/5254ca2719453dcc0b00027d/train/cpp.

In order for me to continue I need to check if the array is working and print it out onto the console. But for some odd reason I get this error:

```
In file included from main.cpp:6:
./solution.cpp:13:10: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('std::ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream<char>') and 'vector<std::string>' (aka 'vector<basic_string<char> >'))
    cout << permarray << endl;
    ~~~~ ^  ~~~~~~~~~
```

My code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <ostream>

using namespace std;

vector<string> permutations(string s) {
  // Your code here
  vector<string> permarray = {};
  if ((int)s.size() == 1) {
    permarray.push_back(s);
    cout << permarray << endl;// error here
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < (int)s.size(); i++) {
    
  }
  return permarray;
  //return std::vector<std::string> {};
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no standard overloaded `operator<<` for `std::ostream` and the class template `std::vector`.

You can output each element of the `vector` using, for example, a range-based `for` loop:

```
for ( const autp &s : permarray )
{
    std::cout << s << '\n';
}
```

If the vector contains only one element then you could write:

```
vector<string> permarray = {};
if ( s.size() == 1) {
  permarray.push_back(s);
  cout << permarray.front() << endl;
}
```

Pay attention to that this casting:

```
if ((int)s.size() == 1) {
```

does not make sense. You could just write:

```
if ( s.size() == 1) {
```